# Hide get parameters names from the URL

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, custom-pages

I know this can be done using Rewrite engine but I am unable to do this 
This is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have this url www.mysite.com/report?page=my-report-name

Now what I want to acheive is this : www.mysite.com/report/my-report-name

The file where I am accessing this get variable name page is reports.php and its not in my root directory 
Path to my file is : root/themes/fount/intel/reports.php

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

To add a routing which points to an external handler PHP file, the following snippet should be used:

```
function wprre_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // pattern with regexps
  $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( '^wp_report/([\w\d-]+)/?', PATH_TO_THE_EXTERNAL_HANDLER.'report.php?report_name=$1' );
}
add_action('init', 'wprre_add_rewrite_rules');
```

You can spot one difference in the parameter handling between add_external_rule() and the add_rewrite_rule. You must use the match selector as the Apache uses it in this case.

This snippet must placed in a file which is always loaded by your plugin or theme. If you write a plugin it can be the main plugin file. In case of theme development it can be the main functions.php file.

The custom GET parameter registration is working as it was mentioned in the Original answer.

*IMPORTANT*

After you edited the rewrite rules via code (external or internal both) you must go to the Permalink settings page in the admin panel and click to the Save button without any changes. This is necessary, because this will flush the rewrite rules and the WP will write into the .htaccess file the rules.

This is the reason why I recommend you to hook on the plugin activation event and register the rewrite rules then and immediately run a flush_rewrite_rules() command.

*NOTES*

The problem with the original answer was that, the add_rewrite_rule() function only works if you route to the default basic index.php. You can only modify the parameters, but you can not route to an external file.

**Original answer**

I think you should use the WordPress API to achieve this. You will need to add a rewrite rule and tag in you theme or plugin with this syntax:

!! Disclaimer this is only working to route to the basic index.php !!

For the routing, add a rewrite rule which points to your PHP file.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^report/([\w-]+)/?', 'index.php?page=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

If you want to use a query parameter which is not in the standard WP parameter list, you need to add that custom parameter name.

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%page%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

Be aware to you use built in parameters if you do not use as the WP API.

In this Codex article you find more details about the topic:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

For troubleshooting and deeper dive understanding you might to check this Codex article too, which describes the proper rewrite rule usage. Because some in circumstances you need to reset the rewrite rules (plugin activation / deactivation).
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: where should I use these functions ? Can I use these in any of my class ? or I should use this in my report.php file ?

Comment: This should go to your plugin file, or if you develop a theme then to the functions.php file.

Comment: I have added this in my functions.php file but its not working. Note that this is my custom page in wordpress template file name is reports.php and the file where I get $_GET['page'] variable is review-details.php file

Comment: function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^report/([\w-]+)/?', 'reports.php?page=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');                                                                              I have added this function reports.php is my template file name in the same directory where functions.php is

Comment: I modified my answer. I was wrong with the add_rewrite_rule() function because it can not used to route an external path. But the snippet in the updated section will work. You can find a demo plugin here, what I wrote to you: 
https://github.com/pappk/WordpressDemos/tree/master/plugins/wp-rewrite-rules-example  Important: after every rewrite rule modification go to the Permalink settings page and click to the Save button to flush the modifications. Good luck!

Comment: yeah thanks I have post my solution that finally worked for me, your answer helped me so I accepted your answer Thanks

Comment: I am glad that you can achieve your goal

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# /anything/anything -> anything.php?url=anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_])/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?url=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**If the page.php filename will always be the same, then do it like this:**

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# /page/anything -> page.php?url=anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: shoul I  replace your code snippet with my .htaccess file ?

Comment: yes... once you can take backup and replace the code in your .htaccess file.

Comment: "RewriteRule . /index.php [L]"                                                                               
                if I remove this line from my .htaccess file my site is not working then

Comment: But you are removing the line from .htaccess file?

Comment: I have post my solution below in my answer that finally worked for me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally this solution worked for me 
I have added this in my functions.php file that is in our theme folder

```
    function rewrite_photo_url(){
add_rewrite_rule('^report/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2671&value=$matches[1]','top');
}
function register_custom_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'value';
    return $query_vars;
}


add_action('init','rewrite_photo_url');
add_filter('query_vars','register_custom_query_vars');
```

and then in my php file I use get_query_var('vale') to get my parameter value

Comment: Honestly, I do not recommend you to hardcode an ID in your code, because you cant deploy the code to different sites without code modification.

Comment: but I don't need to deploy this code on different sites.I am using this on my site only for one page.